# Dumping the configurations for Slim Framework

Tags: php, getter, slim

I am trying to re-reference a config value somewhere in one of my controllers via Slims `\Slim\Helper\Set::Get` method by using

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($data =$app->container->get('data'));
die;
```

Though I can see this being returned in the [GET method](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Helper/Set.php#L77-L92) when using the below code

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if ($this->has($key)) {
        $isInvokable = is_object($this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]) && method_exists($this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)], '__invoke');

        print_r($isInvokable ? $this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]($this) : $this->data[$this->normalizeKey($key)]);
        die;
    }
}
```

My container get never seems to dump this data, and I cannot figure out why. I know when trying to return a non-object value in get, such as `return foo` though, I receive this error, and am thinking it might have something to do with the reason I cannot use a getter as expected. I am asking to figure out how to get the settings/configuration values, if anyone knows a better way to do this please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was Getting a sub of data, and what I was really after was `$data = $app->container->get('settings')` *not* `$data = $app->container->get('data')`